# Converting monthly, quarterly and yearly expenses into a column with only monthly values

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

So I'm doing a household budget, containing the expenses we have. 
To keep data traceability, I want to have the actual expenses shown in the budget, meaning I have some expenses as monthly (like rent, phone bill etc.), some as quaterly (ensurances etc.) and some as annually (ensurances etc.).
To make this easier to calculate, I would like a column with normalized expenses, meaning they are all converted to monthly expenses.

So I've added the expense values [EV] in one column and the unit (monthly, quarterly or annually) [U] in a column next to it.

I'm thinking to have a normalized column next to the [U]-column which contains the converted monthly value [CMV]. 
The [CMV]-column data is to be calculated from the original data based on a check of the [U]-column and then either dividing [EV] by 1 in case of a monthly value, by 3 in case of a quarterly value or by 12 in case of an annually value.

Any suggestions?

I was thinking an IF-statement but having trouble doing the check for three different values ("monthly", "quarterly", "annually"). 
I would like a check for all three values to ensure typo's doesn't provide a false result.

I've seen the INDEX- and MATCH-suggestion in here, but not sure how to apply it here.

=IF(C2="monthly";B2;(IF(C2="quarterly";B2/3;B2/12)))

If the unit of the expense is monthly, the original expense value should be the result of the cell in the normalized column.
If the unit of the expense is quarterly, the original expense value divided by three should be the result of the cell in the normalized column.
If the unit of the expense is annually, the original expense value divided by twelve should be the result of the cell in the normalized column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks something like:

[image: Sample input]

In cell D2, you could try something like:

```
=B2/IF(C2="monthly",1,IF(C2="quarterly",3,IF(C2="annually",12,NA())))
```

This should return `#N/A` if input is not one of: "monthly", "quarterly", "annually".

Alternatively, you could try:

```
=B2/INDEX({1,3,12},MATCH(C2,{"monthly","quarterly","annually"},0))
```

which should also return `#N/A` if the unit is anything other than "monthly", "quarterly", "annually".